# A pde inequality

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, geometric-analysis

Say $M$ be a closed manifold of dimension $6$, we have
\begin{align*}
\Delta f\leq g f-f^2 
\end{align*}
where $g$ is a smooth function on $M$ and $f\geq 0$ (in my case $f=|\phi|^2$ for $\phi$ a section on a vector bundle on $M$). Here $\Delta=d^* d$. Then from maximum principle we can get a $C^0$ bound of $f$ from a $C^0$ bound of $g$, but can we do better like $C^0$ bound of $f$ from some $L^p$ bound of $g$? Any idea or reference is welcome.

Comment: Just to make sure, since you seem to be a geometer. Your Laplacian is the opposite of that of analysts ?

Comment: @DenisSerre Yes. So it is like $\big(-\sum_i\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}\big)$ in local coordinates.